# How do I get "happy" names using Amazon S3 plugin for Grails (via Jets3t)

Tags: grails, amazon-s3, grails-plugin, jets3t

References:

- http://www.grails.org/plugin/amazon-s3
- http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-amazon-s3/trunk/grails-app/services/org/grails/s3/S3AssetService.groovy
- http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-amazon-s3/trunk/grails-app/domain/org/grails/s3/S3Asset.groovy

By "happy" names, I mean the real name of the file I'm uploading... for instance, if I'm putting a file called "foo.png" I'd expect the url to the file to be /foo.png.  Currently, I'm just getting what appears to be a GUID (with no file extension) for the file name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the key field on the S3Asset object to achieve what you need.

I'll update the doco page with more information on this.

Answer (score 2):

With `length`, `inputstream` and `fileName` given from the uploaded file, you should achieve what you want with the following code :

```
        S3Service s3Service = new RestS3Service(new AWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey))
        S3Object up = new S3Object(s3Service.getBucket("myBucketName"), fileName)
        up.setAcl AccessControlList.REST_CANNED_PUBLIC_READ
        up.setContentLength length
        up.setContentType "image/jpeg"
        up.setDataInputStream inputstream
        up = s3Service.putObject(bucket, up)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Actual solution (as provided by @leebutts):

```
import java.io.*;
import org.grails.s3.*;

def s3AssetService;
def file = new File("foo.png"); //assuming this file exists     
def asset = new S3Asset(file);
asset.mimeType = extension;
asset.key = "foo.png"
s3AssetService.put(asset);
```